# Does the references inside the array of strings must be consecutive?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a question regarding the implementation of array of strings.
Let's say that i have this array:

```
string[] strings = new string[4];
```

I know that there is array of 4 place.
The distance between the cells is the same so the array know how to get to each cell.

My questions is regarding the references inside the cells,
Does they also must be with the same distance?
Does each element can be anywhere?

Comment: Are you asking whether the string pointers stored in the array cells have to point to adjacent memory blocks that are also laid out sequentially and at the same distance from each other, like the array elements themselves? If so, then no, they do not, and it would be generally impossible to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. It exactly what i asked.

Answer (score 2):

An array is always allocated in a continuous memory location. If the runtime can't find a continuous location then a runtime exception will be raised. IIRC it will be a `OutOfMemoryException`.

The fact that the array is alocated in a continuos chunk of memory doesn't mean that the objects are. If the type of the array items is a reference type, as is your case with `string`, there is no way this could be so, because its imposible to know when allocating the array how much memory each string will need. The size of the references to the objects is well known, not the size of the objects themselves.

Now, if the type of the array items is a value type, then the size is known before hand and the array will alocate the instances of the objects themselves in a continuos memory slot.

So, to make it short:

- If the array is of a reference type, then the references will be allocated in a continuos memory slot. The referenced objects on the other hand can be placed anywhere in memory.
- If the array is of a value type, the instances themselves will be allocated in a continuos memory slot.